# Should a user be notified about "last modified" time of bitcoin.conf while the bitcoin core wallet is loading?

Tags: bitcoin.conf

I have mentioned details here: https://github.com/bitcoin-core/gui/issues/76

Also what would be the best approach to solve this problem using c++ which works on linux, windows and mac without any issues?

Few solutions are mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40504281/c-how-to-check-the-last-modified-time-of-a-file

[image: Fileinfo]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

If your machine is compromised you can't trust last modified timestamps.

One of the obstacles to Bitcoin adoption is complexity. Developers should keep the user interface as simple and clear as possible. 99.9% of users wouldn't understand the information or how to use it.

A better approach to detecting malicious changes to a configuration file might be to encrypt the configuration file with the wallet password or to store a checksum of the config file in the encrypted wallet file and only alert the user when configuration changes are detected that were not made via the wallet software itself.  But any message should carefully and clearly explain what the situation is without confusing new inexperienced users.

I'm not sure how useful this is since if your wallet config has been maliciously altered the whole computer is untrustworthy.

Comment: > If your machine is compromised you can't trust last modified timestamps

Makes sense

> 99.9% of users wouldn't understand the information or how to use it

Possible. Still may help few.

> alert the user when configuration changes are detected that were not made via the wallet software itself

Interesting

> whole computer is untrustworthy

Yes. And this solution may help notify the user early about it instead of him doing it after few days. Example: you receive emails from services that XYZ change was made to your account, secure account if it wasn't you.

Comment: I think @RedGrittyBrick just means that it's pointless: an attacker who is able to modify the config file can also hide the time of modification... or steal the wallet file... or replacing the bitcoin binary with a version that lies about the timestamp... or just sends your coins directly away. You need to be able to *trust* the system you're running a wallet on; no way around that.

Comment: @Prayank: The point is that if someone can modify your configuration file, they could also modify your Bitcoin installation such that the modification will not raise an alert. Warnings by a service provider work because gaining access to change the password is a different level of access from being notified about such changes.

Comment: @Murch Possible

Comment: @PieterWuille sure attacker can do more than just making changes in config file and I realized such timestamp information may help in some cases although its best to solve it at system level for all important files by user with something like https://sourceforge.net/projects/iwatch on linux which is a tool for detecting changes in filesystem and send email notifications. https://i.imgur.com/EUJnBQE.png